# Trying to remove Windows XP OS without DVD drive nor USB booting ability

Tags: windows, uninstall, live-usb

I have an old laptop (HP DV4000) with dual booting (Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows XP). I would like to get ride of the Windows OS but my problem is that all the tutorials I saw, are requiring to boot from a burned DVD or from a USB flash (to then install the "OS-Uninstaller"). My internal DVD drive is not working, and I use an external DVD drive. But my laptop model doesn't allow to boot from an external source (DVD drive or USB flash). I checked the laptop BIOS and the forums on HP, and it's a known limitation.
Is there any way to install the "OS-uninstaller" straight into the hard disc and run it from there?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Rinzwind is right, and you don't need to do it through a Ubuntu Live CD/USB - you can just delete the unwanted partitions, but I think you want to also remove the 'dual-boot' option to choose XP at startup as well, right? Can you give us some more information about how your internal hard disk(s) are configured? In the terminal, can you type the following command: `sudo fdisk -l` Then copy and paste everything that fdisk prints into the terminal window and add it to your question. That will help us to give you a detailed answer. :)

Comment: From Ubuntu, from software center search for and install gparted. Start it and include an image of the layout of your discs (it is the same as fdisk -l but graphical).

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm at office, so I'll do some checks tonight, when reaching home.
Due to the limitation I have (internal DVD not working and not able to boot from external USB disc/flash) I installed Ubuntu via the "installer for windows" (over the network). I'm not sure if Ubuntu was created in a different partition than Windows. If yes, it seems (based on your comments) that I can just "remove" the partition where windows XP is. 
Then it would be ideal to eliminate the "boot selection" screen, as well as having the extra free space (Hard Disc is not big ...).

Comment: @Rinzwind the only advantage of `fdisk -l` is that it is harder to get wrong and easier for us to interpret the data correctly ^_^

Comment: @Rodolfo wubi? If so be careful... dual boot means you can select on OS from the bootloader (ie. grub) and not from within Windows or from a bootloader that is Windows based.

Answer (score 1):

What have you been smoking? ;-) You are making your life way too difficult: Just install gParted in Ubuntu and you can remove any partition that is not mounted. That, ofcourse, includes your XP partition. From gParted you can also merge the removed partition into your current one or create a separate partition for Ubuntu.

Only if you want to delete the primairy operating system do you need your dvd/usb installer.

---

[gParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted) [image: Install gparted]

[image]

After installation it will be included in the launcher. Click it and you'll get an overview of all your discs, partitions on those discs (and labels identifying those partitions). Mark the XP partition for deleting or for formating to ext4 if you want to include it into Ubuntu.

You can identify Windows partitions due to them having NTFS (or older: FAT) as a filesystem but do take care not deleting any directory that holds personal data if there is a 2nd Windows partition (Ubuntu will mount such partitions so you can extract the data from it to your Ubuntu)

Comment: and to the downvoter: prove me wrong please!

Comment: Could you describe the steps more verbose? I think OP would not figure out how to 'install gParted' neither how to make it work.

Comment: like this? @Danatela :+

Answer (score 0):

Its just something comes into my mind, a bad Idea may be...

Just FORMAT the drive that contains the windows, Most probably C drive

Please comment the result if somebody had allready dont this.

Comment: you cannot format c: drive from windows. gparted is the solution